# TensorFlow memory allocation in GPU

Tags: tensorflow

Using TensorFlow 1.9, I am training a simple neural network with some toy data, to try to understand how TensorFlow allocates memory in the GPU. My graphics card is an NVIDIA GeForce GTX 780 Ti, which has 3GB of GPU memory.

In my code, I have created data and set the batch size such that the amount of memory occupied by one batch is 4GB. This is verified in the code by printing out the number of bytes of the NumPy array containing this data.

When I run this code, I get the following warning message, which is printed out 3 times within each batch:

```
2018-08-03 14:24:50.021264: W tensorflow/core/framework/allocator.cc:108] Allocation of 4000000000 exceeds 10% of system memory.
```

From this, I have two questions:

1) **What does this warning message mean?** 10% of what memory? The GPU memory?

2) **How is a batch of size 4GB able to fit in a GPU of size 3GB?**. Is the batch is divided into sub-batches and each is sent through the GPU independently?

If it is of interest, then my full code is below:

```
# Python imports
import numpy as np

# Tensorflow imports
import tensorflow as tf


# Set some parameters
np.random.seed(0)
num_examples = 2000000
input_size = 1000
num_training_examples = int(0.8 * num_examples)
num_validation_examples = int(0.2 * num_examples)
batch_size = 1000000

# Create the data
print('Creating data')
input_data = np.random.rand(num_examples, input_size).astype(np.float32)
label_data = np.random.rand(num_examples, 1).astype(np.float32)
training_input_data = input_data[:num_training_examples]
training_label_data = label_data[:num_training_examples]
validation_input_data = input_data[num_training_examples:]
validation_label_data = label_data[num_training_examples:]
print('Data created')

# Get the memory for the data
data_memory = training_input_data.nbytes + training_label_data.nbytes + validation_input_data.nbytes + validation_label_data.nbytes
data_memory /= 1e6
print('Dataset memory = ' + str(data_memory) + ' MB')
example_memory = training_input_data[0].nbytes + training_label_data[0].nbytes
batch_memory = example_memory * batch_size
batch_memory /= 1e6
print('Batch memory = ' + str(batch_memory) + ' MB')

# Create the placeholders
input_placeholder = tf.placeholder(dtype=np.float32, shape=[None, input_size])
label_placeholder = tf.placeholder(dtype=np.float32, shape=[None, 1])

# Create the network
x = tf.layers.dense(inputs=input_placeholder, units=input_size, activation=tf.nn.relu)
x = tf.layers.dense(inputs=x, units=50, activation=tf.nn.relu)
x = tf.layers.dense(inputs=x, units=50, activation=tf.nn.relu)
x = tf.layers.dense(inputs=x, units=50, activation=tf.nn.relu)
predictions = tf.layers.dense(inputs=x, units=1)

# Define the loss
loss_op = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(label_placeholder - predictions))

# Define the optimiser
train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001).minimize(loss_op)

# Run a TensorFlow session
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    # Loop over epochs
    num_training_batches = int(num_training_examples / batch_size)
    num_validation_batches = int(num_validation_examples / batch_size)
    training_losses = []
    validation_losses = []
    for epoch_num in range(1000):
        print('epoch ' + str(epoch_num))

        # Training
        batch_loss_sum = 0
        for batch_num in range(num_training_batches):
            print('batch ' + str(batch_num))
            batch_inputs = training_input_data[batch_num * batch_size: (batch_num + 1) * batch_size]
            batch_labels = training_label_data[batch_num * batch_size: (batch_num + 1) * batch_size]
            batch_loss, _ = sess.run([loss_op, train_op], feed_dict={input_placeholder: batch_inputs, label_placeholder: batch_labels})
            batch_loss_sum += batch_loss
        training_loss = batch_loss_sum / num_training_batches

        # Validation
        batch_loss_sum = 0
        for batch_num in range(num_validation_batches):
            batch_inputs = validation_input_data[batch_num * batch_size: (batch_num + 1) * batch_size]
            batch_labels = validation_label_data[batch_num * batch_size: (batch_num + 1) * batch_size]
            batch_loss, _ = sess.run([loss_op, train_op], feed_dict={input_placeholder: batch_inputs, label_placeholder: batch_labels})
            batch_loss_sum += batch_loss
        validation_loss = batch_loss_sum / num_validation_batches
```